# KeystoneJS extending textarray to allow fields

Tags: keystonejs

I am currently using keystoneJS for a project and I have a requirement to allow admins to add additional fields for each deliverable. 
I managed to find textarray, which allows me to add a single line of text but I would need something closer to adding textfields as i would need to add paragraphs of text.

Any advise/direction to extending the functionality or is it not possible?

FYI: I also tried using these two resources to no avail, perhaps due to a lack of knowledge on my end.
- https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/wiki/Create-a-custom-field-type-for-app-development
- https://gist.github.com/JedWatson/8519769

EDIT: i wasnt able to figure out in detail, but changing the arrayfield in mixin to multiline met my use case. Now trying to include two fields in one add.

Comment: Why cannot you add two fields of textArray. One for 'title' & another one for paragraph.

Comment: textarray displays only as a single line of text, suitable for title but unsuitable for paragraphs. I need to be able to allow users to dynamically add textarea in the admin UI depending on the amount of paragraphs they have.